# [ROS2] using native RTI dds *.idl files with ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm wondering if there is an efficient way or best-practice on how to use existing RTI dds idl descriptions with ROS2.
Since we have a complete legacy system running with RTI dds, it would be awesome to be able to communicate with it using ROS2.

I was thinking to have a deep look into ros2 message generation and figure out if it is possible to use existing idls.
As far as i'm aware, when using rti dds as middleware, ros2 is generating idl files form msg definitions as an intermediate step. so hooking inbetween that process with existing idl files seems reasonable.

BR
Jochen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271551/%5Bros2%5D-using-native-rti-dds-*.idl-files-with-ros2/) by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-26**:
I know it's confusing, but following a recent discussion (on ROS Discourse: [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-support-ros-answers/2620)), ROS2 questions are right now better asked in the `ng-ros` category on ROS Discourse.

**Comment by [MTDzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/35839/mtdzi/) on 2020-08-11**:
I've stumbled upon a large repo containing a bunch of `.msg` files which might serve as inspiration for manually converting `.idl` files into `.msg`: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces
That's not what the OP wanted, so this is not an actual answer but just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently there is no out-of-the-box way to provide an `.idl` file directly and use that. All `.idl` files are being generated from the `.msg` files and they use a pretty custom mapping (which adds namespaces as well as suffixes) so your existing `.idl` files will very likely not match the generated types exactly.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on 2017-09-26**:
thanks for pointing that out to me again  :-) i just re-discovered the discussion at https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-and-dds-messaging/1556
Although I have to say that at is kind of a bummer to not being able to smoothly communicate with existing DDS Systems.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-09-26**:
Both systems are able to "smoothly" communicate. For your use case you would need to generate `.msg` files from `.idl` files which nobody has implemented. I think nobody has done that since there are cases where that transformation isn't possible since IDL supports more features than `.msg`.